# Stuck transaction tried everything!

Tags: ether, error

So basically, my transaction got stuck, 0x5a370170b66b3748665d6615363d6d8710f692bae87ffbcf5a9dd839029847d8  tried to cancel transaction, speed up etc doesn't work, tried to resubmit transaction via NONCE, nothing, error keeps popin out[image]

Max GWEI used, nothing helps, tried to send multiple times, now I have 3 different transactions stuck, please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send another transaction with nonce 228 and value 0 to your own wallet, setting gas to market or aggresive.
You sent 2 more transactions incrementing the nonce, so you will need to customize it to 228, follow this guide to do it with Metamask: https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360015489251-How-to-Speed-Up-or-Cancel-a-Pending-Transaction

Answer (score 0):

5.5 gwei is far to little to hope to ever be included on chain, for reference, the current gas price is 69 gwei (nice). Also, according to tenderly ( https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x5a370170b66b3748665d6615363d6d8710f692bae87ffbcf5a9dd839029847d8) your transaction is going to revert anyways if it's ever included, probably the NFT you're trying to buy has  already been sold while your transaction was pending. If metamask can't replace or cancel your transaction manually for some reason, you can still do it manually, here's a little guide :

- in metamask go to : settings => advanced => customize transaction nonce, that will make the tx s nonce show up in the transaction's confirmation screen.
- Create a new transaction, you're going to send 0 ether to yourself, using the recommended gas price (just, don't touch it, or set it to fast, and you should be all good). That transaction needs to have the same nonce as the currently stuck transaction (228).

It will replace the current transaction with nonce 228 (the stuck one) in the mempool, effectively cancelling it.
Hope that helps, feel free to ask if you need any prescisions

Comment: Thanks guys, for some reason i couldn't replace transaction by nonce on my PC, but I tried on my phone it worked. Thanks a lot!